# How can I avoid being killed by The Masked Defiler?

Tags: phantom-abyss

Of the three Guardians, The Masked Defiler is the one that gives me the most trouble. The poison balls it shoots at you can take up a large area, and slow your movement. If you spend too long in the poison gas cloud, you'll take damage.

In the larger rooms it usually isn't a problem, since I can either move through the room quick enough to stay ahead of any poison, or I can use the large space to avoid the gas clouds by taking a safer path (or just wait around until the gas clouds clear). In those tight, trap filled hallways, though, neither of these seem like an option. Going fast will just get me killed by traps, and going slow will just get me killed by the poison (since I can't exactly dodge a giant gas cloud in a narrow hallway). Even some larger rooms can run into issues depending on the trap layout, since they restrict my movement enough that dodging and going fast are no longer options.

So I'm at a loss as how to deal with The Masked Defiler. Are there any strategies I can leverage, or mechanics I should be aware of to make The Masked Defiler easier to deal with? *How can I avoid being killed by The Masked Defiler?*

Comment: Didn't play the game so won't make an answer, but you might be interested in reading [this steam discussion](https://steamcommunity.com/app/989440/discussions/0/3051733836214095100/) talking about Masked Defiler. There seem to be some tips that might help you when against this guardian.